# check the checkbox if name and value match with the input checkbox field

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

**.html**

```js
var url = "http: //127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=san&language=1&cast=1&language=2&cast=3";
  existingUrl(var);

function existingUrl(fullUrl) {
  $('.language').each(function() {
    var hasValue = fullUrl.indexOf($(this).val());
    if (hasValue != -1)
      this.checked = true;

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">


  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" hidden> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="1" value="1"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="2" value="1"> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="3" value="2"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="4" value="3"> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

It work fine if all the checkbox input value have different value.If we try with different name having same value it checked all checkbox with that value.

Comment: Please explain how the current behavior differs from the behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if we have `//127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=san&language=1` in url it checked all the checkbox with value 1 (cast and language checkbox with value1) not just langauge checkbox with value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the duplicate parameter names don't really allow you to use `URLSearchParams`, I'd split on `&` and `=` to generate key/value pairs. For each, you could use attribute selectors to target and check the corresponding items.

```js
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=&language=1&cast=3';

function existingUrl(fullUrl) {
  let query = fullUrl.split("?")[1];                                //?language=1&cast=3
  query.split("&").forEach(param => {                               //split on "&"
    let [name, value] = param.split("=");                           //split on "=" to get name/value pairs
    let valueSelector = value ? `[value=${value}]` : '';            //account for null value
    $(`input[name=${name}]${valueSelector}`).prop("checked", true); //check corresponding input
  });
}

existingUrl(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" hidden> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="1" value="1"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="2" value="1"> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="3" value="2"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="4" value="3">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: URLSearchParams has getAll method which allows to get parameters with same name

Comment: your code doesn't work if i put put param with empty params.Example:`search/?name=&language=1&language=2`

Answer (score 2):

You can find items from a map of queries you can compare them by generating key/value pair of each item by `$(this).prop('name') + '=' + $(this).val()` this logic and look into your existing query array which is created by all queryparams spliced by `&`

```js
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=san&language=1&cast=1&language=2&cast=3';
existingUrl(url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1));

function existingUrl(query) {
  var urlparts = query.split('&');
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    this.checked = urlparts.indexOf($(this).prop('name') + '=' + $(this).val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" hidden> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="1" value="1"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="2" value="1"> language
  <input type="checkbox" name="language" class="language" id="3" value="2"> cast
  <input type="checkbox" name="cast" class="cast" id="4" value="3">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what do yo mean?? you want to derive from your checkboxes or from url? which is dynamic?

Comment: Anyhow I updated to `input[type=checkbox]` hope now it helps

Answer (score 0):

Change val() to id

```
function existingUrl(fullUrl) {
  $('.language').each(function() {
    var hasValue = fullUrl.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
    if (hasValue != -1)
      this.checked = true;

  });
}
```

**Note:** it is a bad practice using `indexOf` with `strings`, lets say you have language=111 in url then that will also work for language 1 and 11 which is not intended. 
Best approach is to get url parameter values in an array and then using `indexOf` will be no harm.

Comment: I am not passing id of checkbox in url.

Comment: ok, if it is value then what you are trying to acheive ? it will be checking all with same value. You must elaborate your need so that one can give you a better idea.

Comment: I  just want only those chebox will checked whose name and value are matches with url params not just on value match.

Comment: Okay, I have posted another answer, much cleaner for your need.

Answer (score 0):

convert url into string and then pass it to function.

```
var url = 'http: //127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=san&language=1&cast=1&language=2&cast=3';
existingUrl(url);
```

Comment: That not a problem i edit my question.I  just want only those chebox will checked whose name and value are matches with url params not just on value match.

Answer (score 0):

Should work exactly what you need:

```
var url = new URL(url_string);
var languageParams = url.searchParams.getAll("language");

$('.language').each(function() {
      this.checked = languageParams.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1;
});
```

Comment: No there are multiple param in url which i have not mentions.Your code is completly hardcoded.Thank for help tho.